# What are the pods on stage 1 of Blue Origin's New Glenn?

Tags: blue-origin, new-shepard, new-glenn

I noticed New Glenn has two pods near the bottom of its first stage. Falcon 9 has four pods in the same area, and those are legs. But New Glenn's pods protrude more and they almost look like fins, at least in some renderings. Curious: Are the pods landing legs, fins, or something else?

[image]

**EDIT**

New Shepard has similar pods at the bottom. In that vehicle they are steering fins. You can see them moving in pre-launch checks done in a [test launch here](https://youtu.be/domwsgorRW0?t=6752). So the pods on New Glenn are probably steering fins as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what that image is? A photograph of an actual rocket or a drawing of an imagined design?

Comment: You caught it before I caught it. All edited out :)

Comment: I must be too bored at work haha ;)

Answer (score 5):

Based on other promotional images of New Glenn that show it from different angles, they would appear to be fins:

(Note how the edge appears to be sharp, suggesting a thin shape)

[image]
([source](https://www.blueorigin.com/assets/photos/new-glenn/blueorigin_newglenn_ascent_web.jpg))

Answer (score 2):

They are "strakes" aka fins.

> Large aerodynamic strakes on the aft end
> of the tanks give the returning first stage enhanced cross-range during descent
> and reentry.

Source: [New Glenn Payload User's Guide](https://yellowdragonblogdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/new_glenn_payload_users_guide_rev_c.pdf) page 16